# Triangular UIImageView mask IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

Check attached screenshot.

[image]

This is What I have done. I have created `UIImageView` in storyboard and assign image (pink triangular image) to `imageView`. I have used gesture to recognize drag (right side, half of screen) event on `image`.

Actually, I need drag event only when I click and drag from pink portion but problem is when I click and drag outside of pink area nearby image also image is also dragged. I have not used any masking. Just put `imageView` on storyboard. Can you give me source code of my problem of how to solve this?

Comment: Why not to add gesture recognizer to that small image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the colour of the touch point and can compare with the required one. Here is a sample code to achieve this

```
- (UIColor *) colorOfPoint:(CGPoint)point {     unsigned char pixel[4] = {0};

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask & kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -point.x, -point.y);

    [self.layer renderInContext:context];

    CGContextRelease(context);  CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    //NSLog(@"pixel: %d %d %d %d", pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2], pixel[3]);

    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:pixel[0]/255.0 green:pixel[1]/255.0 blue:pixel[2]/255.0 alpha:pixel[3]/255.0];

    return color; }
```